# Is there a way to flip/reverse a surge function?

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to fit a model for the data points (in blue) using a surge function, but do not know how to make it so the function's maximum is farther down the x axis. Is there a way I could flip the function or something so that the local maximum is in the same area as the blue points? 
If not, is there a function or equation that anyone recommends would fit properly? [function and points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n252k.png)

Comment: You would have to quite dramatically modify the form of the equation. You cannot really achieve this with functions of the form
$$
a\cdot xe^{-bx}
$$
So do you need to have the function exactly in this form, or can you be more creative with your function selection?

Comment: @MattiP. thank you for the reply. No, I do not need the function in this form - it can be whatever it needs to be.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions to this kind of problem, and it's really an art form more than an exact science. Maybe something like this would work? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0dhsllpwxk

Comment: @MattiP. you're a legend, thank you :) I will play around with the values and see what happens.

Comment: How did your tests work out? Did you find a suiting result? I'm interested to hear :)

Comment: I know it's two years late, but yes I basically just used yours as a template and tweaked a few numbers. Thanks for helping me pass high school haha